# How to make ToC title look like the other titles in my report

Tags: table-of-contents, report

completely new to LaTeX here. I am writing a report class document. And unfortunately the title of the ToC is automatically serif and larger than the automatic titles when i use the *section{} command. How do I make the Contents title look as the other titles do (sans serif and automatic section size). I have attached two pictures, I want "Contents" to look like "Introduction". Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\sffamily
\linespread{1.45}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-1em}
\tableofcontents
```

[image: How the contents page currently looks]

[image: How the font should look]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a compilable code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Little doubt this is addressed somewhere.  So, if this is a duplicate, then it's a duplicate, but it's some easier to address this than to look for where else this may be addressed.  See if this works.  In your preamble, i.e., somewhere prior to `begin{document}`, add a line something like this: `\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\bfseries\sffamily}`.  In testing this, the font sizes are 12pt in both ToC name and ToC contents.  To change that, add something like `\large` or `\Large` or `\huge`, if you need the larger size font(s).

Comment: `\chapter` is the highest structuring command you should use in your text. If you need the sectioning/chapter titles to be a little smaller ... there are packages to use. Or use a KOMA-class (`scrreprt`), it provides an easy interface.

Comment: @Johannes_B It's interesting how a Q is "read" differently.  We'll know more when we hear back, but I think the focus here is sans serif v. serif, with a preference on sans, in the title lines, with a special focus on the `\contentsname` formal.

Comment: Is there any news here? Right now, the question is a bit unclear and an answer might not suit your needs. Please clarify/specify by providing a minimal working example.